# Single Connection String with Multiple Entity Framework Models?

Tags: entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

At work we currently have a very large web application with a connection to a massive database. We have been using Entity Framework for a while now and to make things easier we divided the database into many Entity models. This works well for us but we ran into an issue. Each EF model needs its own connection string due to the metadata part of the connection string. Managing so many connection string is a pain.

Now I have a solution that I think will work. I am going to create a class that will have the metadata info saved as a property also concatenated to the standard connection string in the web.config. So when we use the connection string "Database.EntityConnectionString" it will give me the Entity Connection string but we only have to manage a single connection string in the web.config. We will still have to manage the class with the metadata but Models don't change very much and we don't create them often so maintenance should be fine. My question, is there a better way of dealing with this issue or how would you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I have implemented my solution to this problem:

```
namespace DBLibrary
{
    public enum Models
    {
        Model1,
        Model2    
    }

    public static class Database
    {
        public static string EntitiesConnectionString(Models model)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString);

            builder["MultipleActiveResultSets"] = true;
            builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;

            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

            switch (model)
            {
                case Models.Model1:
                    entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
                    return entityBuilder.ToString();
                case Models.Model2:
                    entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl";
                    return entityBuilder.ToString();
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid model, no connection string defined");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still need to clean up the code and all but I think this give you a good idea on how this can be implemented. I would still be very interested if there are different and better ways of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: I know it is a bit old but how did you use it

Answer (score 1):

Add Default Construction in your Class

```
public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item>Items get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemDetail> ItemDetails { get; set; }

    public ItemContext ()
    {

        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I have solved it by following way:

I have created two edmx file, but while creating second edmx file, i ignored the connection string to be save in  config file. This way my  config file will hold only one Connection string. 
Then i modified following lines in my connection string:

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=abc;initial catalog=mydb;persist security info=True;user id=myuser;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Just replace "res://model1.csdl" with **"res://*/"** and it works like a charm.

You can specify this connection name in constructor of your dbcontext class like:

```
public MyDbContext() : base("name=NameOfYourConnectionString") //  Name of your connection string
{ }
```

Note: I am using Entity Framework 5.0.

Comment: This will not work if your models contain overlapping types (ie, you have the same table referenced in multiple models)

Comment: Well, for that you can change the duplicate Entity name in Edmx itself. I had also same table referenced in multiple model, but i rename the entityset name in edmx entityset property to avoid duplicate entity!