# Should all classes be in on Entity Framework file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I am trying to create entity framework replacements for my class files.

Aka, `edmx` files.

I created one already, with my class in.

Now I want to create a second. However, I cannot use the same connection `namespaceEntities` from my `config` file...

Which leads me to believe, that there should only be one `edmx` file, or I need multiple duplicates of a connection string.

How do you re-use the same connection string. And `using (var db = new namespaceEntities())` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate you Entities you could also open your current edmx file, from the menu go View -> Other Windows -> Entity Data Model Browser.

In the browser window on your right you can go to Diagrams, right click on it and add new Diagram.

There you can put your new Entity.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: I get as far as the browser. there is no Diagrams option there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many `EDMX` as you need, Since they are models keep it in one file if it's the same context but add  different one if needed.

Now to answer the question about reusing connection string you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3119825/1880431).